# Extend Java 6 with TLSv1.1 support

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, cryptography

My apllication is deployed on Tomcat 6 with Java 6, I want to restrict the SSL protocol to use only **TLSv1.1**. According to Java 6 [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) JCE isn't supporting TLSv1.1 while Java 7 does.

Upgrade my Java version isn't acceptable. There is any providers that implements TLSv1.1 protocol that I can integrate to my java?

Since it's production system I am looking for quick and safe fix. I thought to front end my application server with apache web server at the same host(which supports TLSv1.1 through openssl) and use him as a proxy server. Unfortunately my physical resources are low.

Any other ideas are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't upgrading Java an option? Java 6 has been EOL for a while, and Java 8 is officially out now.

Comment: We did upgrade our java version in newer releases of our product, this specific client has an old version.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html#HTTPS It would appear the APR uses openSSL directly, if I'm reading that right.

Comment: @BrianRoach It does, but I didn't realize the APR connectors were available on a release that still supported 6. That's the one to go with if possible.

Comment: It's not possible. I see the next output in catalina.out log: INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path..

Comment: @MaximKirilov That just means it isn't installed. So download and install it.

Comment: @EJP It's a production environment so it's problematic to install new software there.

Comment: "...this specific client has an old version..." - there's nothing you can do because you don't control the clients. TLS v1.0 is usually the minimum common denominator (thankfully, SSL v3 is gone).

Comment: @MaximKirilov Then you're stuck. I would advise the Apache HTTP front-end as it's pretty easy to do.

Comment: Running this on a production environment is all the more reason to use up to date software that receives security updates and support.

Answer (score 1):

Front it with a system that does the SSL and does get security updates. You can run apache using the connector - if you still trust this - or setup a Java application (a newer version of Tomcat?) to act as an SSL proxy (connecting to port 80 of your server, if this is acceptable to you).